# Basic arithmetic giving strange value

Tags: math, fortran

I am trying to compute a value which takes the functional form x+10(y+10(z+10(w+10(u+1000v))))). Let's say x = y = z = w = 1, u = 3 and v = 2. Then this should come out to 20031111. I'd like this as a floating point number, not an integer. When I use the code

```
output = x+10(y+10(z+10(w+10(u+1000v)))))
```

I get 20031111 as expected. However, when I use

```
output = 1.0(x+10(y+10(z+10(w+10(u+1000v))))))
```

I get 20031112.000, which is wrong. What is going on here?

By the way, if I pre-multiply by 1.D0 instead of 1.0, I get the right answer again. But I don't understand why.

Comment: Read Goldberg's paper on floating point arithmetic.  Google's your friend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Floating point numbers are [approximations](http://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/Real+precision) of real numbers. A default real type in Fortran cannot represent a number with 8 significant algarisms preciselly. The best approximation of the value will be then stored in the variable, and in your case, it is `2.0031112E+07`.

You can do the following test:

```
real :: output
integer :: x = 1, y = 1, z = 1, w = 1, u = 3, v = 2
! (...)
output = 1.0 *(x + 10 *(y + 10 * (z + 10 * (w + 10 * (u + 1000 * v)))))
print*, output + 2   ! prints: 2.0031114+07
print*, output + 1   ! prints: 2.0031112+07
print*, output       ! prints: 2.0031112+07
print*, output - 1   ! prints: 2.0031112+07
print*, output - 2   ! prints: 2.0031110+07
```

As a solution, you have to use a real type with a kind parameter that can represent the data with the precision you want. Fortran provides an intrinsic function to help you choose the minimum kind that fits a precision, `selected_real_kind`.

Example:

```
integer, parameter :: wp = selected_real_kind(8) ! 8 precision digits
real(wp) :: output    ! <- here you use wp as the kind parameter
integer :: x = 1, y = 1, z = 1, w = 1, u = 3, v = 2
! (...)
! you can also apply the kind parameter to litreals as below, like 1.0_wp
output = 1.0_wp *(x + 10 *(y + 10 * (z + 10 * (w + 10 * (u + 1000 * v)))))
print*, output + 2   ! prints: 20031113.0000000
print*, output + 1   ! prints: 20031112.0000000
print*, output       ! prints: 20031111.0000000
print*, output - 1   ! prints: 20031110.0000000
print*, output - 2   ! prints: 20031109.0000000
```

> By the way, if I pre-multiply by 1.D0 instead of 1.0, I get the right answer again. But I don't understand why.

The suffix `D0` is a convenient shorthand for declaring a real literal with the kind parameter corresponding to `double precision` type specification, that (in your system) has enough precision to accurately represent the value. (Note that, for it to work, you would need do declare `output`as a `double precision` variable.)

Is is recommended, though, to use the approach I proposed before, that is portable and gives you more control over the data type.

Comment: I can't reproduce your 1.D0 result, but it could depend on the round-off approach of the compiler being used. Don't all Fortran compilers now support IEEE 754 ?

Comment: I see, but your example still gets the value wrong even when you included the _wp on the 1.0. What's going on there?

Comment: @F.User, the answer is fine, I just typed it wrong. It is corrected now.

Comment: @johncampbell, indeed if you store it back to a default kind real variable, the precision is lost. I suppose OP tested it printing the result expression directly to screen, without storing - in this case a `double precision` value were printed.

Answer (score 1):

You are hitting the limit of representable integers in a floating point representation.

By multiplying your result with `1.0`, you convert your result to a default `REAL` and only a few integers can be represented exactly by such a number.

The [Fortran standard](https://j3-fortran.org/doc/year/10/10-007.pdf) never states that a `REAL` of any kind should represent an [IEEE-754 floating point number](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=4610935). The representation of `REAL` is processor dependent. Nonetheless, the most common representation is that of IEEE-754. To this end, we assume that your type `REAL` is an [IEEE-754 binary32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format), better known as Single-precision floating-point format.

In this format, integers in the range `[-16777216,16777216]` can be exactly represented. This number resembles `2**24` (23 bits fractional part and an extra default 1).

When multiplying with `1.0D0` you converted the integer to a `DOUBLE PRECISION` number, most commonly represented by an [IEEE-754 binary64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format), better known as Double-precision floating-point format. Here, you can represent all integers in the range `[-9007199254740992,9007199254740992]`.

As you see, the number `20031111` falls outside of the range of the [IEEE-754 binary32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) representation and is thus approximated, while it falls in the range of the [IEEE-754 binary64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) representation.